# Expanding data.frame rows based on single field

Tags: r, reshape

I have a simple data set in the form:

```
From,To,Date,Subject
```

I would like to reshape this data such that lines as:

```
e1,e2;e3;e4,d1,s1
```

Get expanded too:

```
e1,e2,d1,s1
e1,e3,d1,s1
e1,e4,d1,s1
```

Now, I get this done with a for loop over my data frame and constructing a new one on the fly, but I wondered if there is more "R"-way of doing this?

**Edit:**
This is what I currently have, it works but is kind of ugly (and showing my still somewhat limited R-skills):

```
filteredEmailsExpanded <- NULL
toCol <- 2
for (row in 1:nrow(filteredEmails)) {
  receivers <- sapply(strsplit(filteredEmails[row, toCol], ","), function(x) gsub(" ", "", ))
  for (receiver in receivers) {
    newRow <- rep(filteredEmails[row,], times = 1)
    newRow$To <- receiver
    rbind(filteredEmailsExpanded, newRow)
  }
}
```

Comment: please show actual code, cause this isn't very clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you first expand your data frame (call it `d`), repeating the ith row n(i) times, where n(i) is the number of occurences of ';' in `d$To[i]`, and then you replace `d$To` by these occurences? I've added an extra row to your example data to illustrate this better

```
d <- data.frame(
        From = c("e1", "e5"), 
        To = c("e2;e3;e4", "e6;e7"),
        Date = c("d1", "d2"),
        Subject = c("s1", "s2"),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

v <- strsplit(d$To, ";")
lengths <- sapply(v, length)
d <- d[rep(1:nrow(d), lengths), ]
d$To <- unlist(v)
```

Comment: Yes, this was exactly the kind of R-trickery that I'm still lacking and was looking for. Excellent answer, straight to the point!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at my "splitstackshape" package, in particular, the function `concat.split.multiple` which has a "long" argument.

Using @konvas's sample data, try:

```
library(splitstackshape)
concat.split.multiple(d, "To", ";", "long")
#   From Date Subject time   To
# 1   e1   d1      s1    1   e2
# 2   e5   d2      s2    1   e6
# 3   e1   d1      s1    2   e3
# 4   e5   d2      s2    2   e7
# 5   e1   d1      s1    3   e4
# 6   e5   d2      s2    3 <NA>
```

Alternatively, check out its successor function (which hasn't yet made it into the package). The successor is presently called [**`cSplit`** and is available as a Gist](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733). It is *much* faster but just as easy to use:

```
## cSplit(indt = d, splitCols = "To", sep = ";", direction = "long")
cSplit(d, "To", ";", "long")
#    From To Date Subject
# 1:   e1 e2   d1      s1
# 2:   e1 e3   d1      s1
# 3:   e1 e4   d1      s1
# 4:   e5 e6   d2      s2
# 5:   e5 e7   d2      s2
```

Comment: Interesting addition to the stated question. Indeed solves my problem as well with less lines of code (good!) at the cost of an extra dependency.

Comment: @BertjanBroeksema, plus it's *fast* :-)